# Оставить только имена компьютеров в запросе к LDAP

Tags: delphi, ldap

Следующими командами осуществляю подключение к LDAP:

```
  ADOQuery2.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('Select CN from ' + QuotedStr('LDAP://gpnd5.local'));
  ADOQuery2.Open;
  ADOQuery2.Sort := 'CN';
```

Получаю список всего что хранится в ActiveDirectory

Что добавить в SQL-запрос, чтобы получить только список компьютеров?

Пробовал вот так:

```
 ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('Select CN from ' + QuotedStr('LDAP://gpnd5.local;(&(objectClass=Computer));CN; subtree'));
```

Получаю ошибку: **Указан недопустимый dn-синтаксис**

Comment: *Что добавить в SQL-запрос, чтобы получить только список компьютеров?* Соответствующее WHERE-выражение.

Comment: Пробовал вот так: ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('Select CN from ' + QuotedStr('LDAP://gpnd5.local')+'where ObjectClass=Computer'); Не выполняется

Comment: `Computer` - это строковое значение-литерал, следовательно, оно должно быть обрамлено кавычками. Т.е. итоговый текст запроса должен получиться `SELECT CN FROM 'LDAP://gpnd5.local' WHERE ObjectClass='Computer'`

Comment: Вот так наверное не совсем верно будет:  ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('Select CN from ' + QuotedStr('LDAP://gpnd5.local')+'WHERE ObjectClass="Computer"'); ?

Comment: PS. Что-то я не припоминаю такого значения для `ObjectClass` в стандартной схеме... и в https://pro-ldap.ru/tr/zytrax/ape/core-schema.html его не числится. Проверьте, правильно ли пишете значение, по документации на расширение схемы.

Comment: *Вот так наверное не совсем верно будет:* Так будет гарантированно неверно, хотя бы по причине отсутствия пробела перед WHERE. А вот замена простой кавычки на двойную емнип для ADO некритично.